# Cannot see all SharePoint Libraries using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

This is my first time attempting something like this, so I'm hoping this will be a simple question to answer for some of you. I have a client site where I'm trying to iterate through a collection of files to look for files that don't have a specific column value (sharepointnewkey). Through the web interface, I can get to the SharePoint site, browse the folders, and see all of the contents just fine. When I connect to the SharePoint through PowerShell, I don't see anything referencing the particular site:

[image: Get-SPOSite -detailed | SELECT Url]

The site that should be showing up in this list should look something like:

[image: https://acmeinc.sharepoint.com/SalesAnvilsConnect]

It doesn't appear in the list. From there, it's a simple matter of running a script to do a collection on the files and build the list that I need. I am a Global Admin and Application Admin for the site, the latter being required to execute PowerShell scripts against the SharePoint. At this point, I can't seem to find anything specific to the problem I'm having. Any help you can provide at this point is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: Since posting this, I have also come to learn that the site I'm trying to find does not show up in the list of active sites in the admin console, either.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the site was created, but I think you are looking at Site Collections vs. Subsites. The word "site" is often used for both.

This is a Site Collection named "Marketing":

```
https://acmeinc.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing
```

This is a Subsite of the "Marketing" Site Collection:

```
https://acmeinc.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing/project1
```

This is the top level Site Collection of your SharePoint tenant:

```
https://acmeinc.sharepoint.com/
```

This is Subsite in the top level Site Collection of your SharePoint tenant:

```
https://acmeinc.sharepoint.com/SalesAnvilsConnect
```

Which PowerShell library are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Mike - sorry about the delay in getting back to you on it. Based on what you've said, mine would be a Subsite in the top level Site Collection:



`https://acmeinc.sharepoint.com/SalesAnvilsConnect`



What I'm trying to do now is iterate all of the subfolders and files, making a list of any files (and their location) that do not contain a valid site key.